# How to extract only EXEC queries from SQL procedures?

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I am trying to extract only `EXEC` queries from SQL procedures like the one shown below:

```
USE [test]

ALTER PROC [dbo].[USP_TEST]
@idx int 
AS

EXEC USP_TEST_BY_IDX @idx

print("TEST")

EXEC USP_TEST_CHECK
```

Please note that this is just an example, and there are many complex procedures where I need to extract only `EXEC` queries.

The result I want to achieve is an array of all `EXEC` queries in the procedure, like this:

```
['EXEC USP_TEXT_BY_IDX @idx', 'EXEC USP_TEXT_CHECK]
```

However, every `EXEC` (Transact-SQL) query is one line, and I do not know how to extract the entire query to the end of the line.

Currently, I am using the following script to extract only `EXEC` from the procedure:

```
let str = document.getElementById("procedure").innerText;
str.match(/exec/gmi);
```

If I want to extract the entire `EXEC` query to the end of the line, what changes do I need to make in my regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your regex only matches `exec` and not the whole line is because you are not using any wildcard or quantifier to match the rest of the characters after `exec`. You need to use something like `.*` or `.+` to match any character zero or more times or one or more times respectively.

For example, if you want to match the whole line that starts with `exec`, you can use this regex:

```
/exec.*/gmi
```

This will match any character after `exec` until the end of the line. If you want to match only the words after `exec`, you can use this regex:

```
/exec\s+(\w+)/gmi
```

This will match one or more whitespace characters `(\s+)` after `exec` and then one or more word characters `(\w+)` until the end of the word. The parentheses `()` create a capturing group that you can access later.